# How to create partition on table column with datepart

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

I request help in creating a partition on EXISTING table on column type Datatime(7)
by Datepart day.

The table has a created column.
Is there a way to create a partition to table by datepart function Day??
(datepart(DAY,[Created]))

Additional information:

Here is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SagaEvents](
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[EventType] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
[EventDescription] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
[JsonDetails] [nvarchar](1024) NULL,
[Created] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL)
```

I plan on doing this to create a truncate partition on the above table.
The current step that i arrive is:

1. Create Partition function for a month (with one partition empty)
   Script:

   CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PF_SagaRing (TINYINT)
   AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,
   13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
   21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32)
2. Create partition schema :
   script

   CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PS_SagaRing
   AS PARTITION PF_SagaRing ALL TO ('PRIMARY')

Now i need to alter the table ( that part i got covered as there is a downtime for that deploy)
and add the partition function to the table.

How do i add a partition to the existing table without adding a computed persisted column??

Thanks

Comment: May I ask your reason for partitioning by day? I once encountered a large table partitioned this way (30+ billion rows, several years of history) and it took days to "unshard" it, partitioning by month (date range) instead. Performance was great after fixing the mistake.

Comment: I plan on deleting the data that is greater than 30 days. I've created a stored procedure that deletes the next day partition. The logic is a Rotating Log / Ring Buffer as explained on this link : https://web.archive.org/web/20190209220048/http://kejser.org/table-pattern-rotating-log-ring-buffer/

Comment: You will need either a materialized column with the day or a persisted computed column. Personally, I'd use a daily sliding window on `Created`.

Comment: Or partition by ID, and truncate partitions whose newest row is over 30 days old.  That way you don't need to drop the clustered index, or add Created to it.

Comment: Thanks, It's a good advice. It may be a newbie question - now i need to to query the partition newst value before running the truncate partition. Is there a way to query the rows of the specific partition? Also when i partition by ID i'll have to partition the function by Range and not by Values. Could this still be done by partition function by Values that way i will loop over the partition?